# Live spectrogram in windows

Tags: windows, audio, spectrogram

this is my first question on the forum, and I hope I'm in the right place!

I was looking for a cool way to make my windows pc screens less boring while sending sound to my desktop speakers. Aside from that, I've always found spectrograms really classy (you know, the bar graphs that show in real time the frequencies sent to the speakers).

Naturally, I thought I could display a spectrogram on my PC screen, but it has to be in sync with the sound I'm hearing. So the easiest thing to do would seem to be to find software that analyzes the sound as it comes out of the PC, and displays the spectrogram live. Except that this simple idea doesn't lead me anywhere*.

So I'm counting on you to help me find a solution, the best would be the name of a software that can do that. If not, maybe an alternative will do the trick!

Thanks in advance ;)

- Actually, I do find some software or websites that offer spectrograms of all shapes and colors, but of all those I've tried, I'm always obliged to give them 1 audio track, wait for them to analyze it, and then I can visualize the spectrogram. But I'm looking for a plug-in that allows me to have this spectrogram live, and indifferent to the origin of the sound (basically, it has to work if I'm listening to music from spotify, my audio file management software (MusicBee), youtube, internet...).

Comment: I would recommend coding your own in https://processing.org

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that there's better solutions out there but you could use SFS/RTSPECT by University College London. It might be different on different systems but to get to use my system audio I had to enable "Stereo Mix" in my audio devices and set it up as an audio input. Only issue is that you might not be able to use your microphone at the same time.